# Can't verify_password correctly

Tags: php, mysql

trying to password_verify, but anyway nothing works and i dont understand what is the real problem, can some1 explain? I dont know why my $hash returns true EVEN if the passwords do not match and then my next IF statement is being executed for no reason

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$hash_pwd = $row['password'];
$hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);
if ($hash !== 0 && $emailErr2 == "" && $passwordErr2 == "") {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$hash_pwd'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }  else {
    echo "wrong";
    }

}
```

Comment: from where this `$emailErr2 and $passwordErr2` variables comes into picture? Also when you have record then why again doing query

Comment: from code above that i didn't post (would've been too much)

Comment: the problem isn't in these variables

Comment: Try this much only:- `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$hash_pwd = $row['password'];
$hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);

if ($hash === true) {
 echo "SUCCESS";
}  else {
 echo "wrong";
}` Also query is open for SQL Injection so use `prepared statements`

Comment: @mickmackusa If you have nothing useful to say, refuse commenting

Comment: Both of my comments are helpful.  Your question will not only serve you but others in the future.  Providing an intelligent, meaningful, accurate title will help future SO readers to find your question and draw upon the knowledge on the page.  About the query security, you are applying user input directly to database queries.  You should be using, at minimum, prepared statements with placeholders to avoid injection attacks.  There is nothing offensive about my comments.  I am here to help (you, StackOverflow, and future readers).

Comment: could be data type issue. Try using just `!=` instead of `!==`

Comment: it certainly is a data type issue. `password_verify` returns `boolean` type and you check if it is not equal to `0` which it always will be, since `0` is an `int`eger. `!==` not only checks if the value is "equal" but also if it's the same type. If your passwords don't match even though they should, then your password-hashing and -storing might be ... flawed as well, or you don't actually retrieve the password from POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is the conditional check of `$hash`.

The [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) says:

> Return Values
>
> Returns the hashed password, or FALSE on failure.

This is a demonstration as to why your "[not identical comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)" is letting you down.

```
$hash = true;
if($hash!==0){
    echo "true passes";
}else{
    echo "true fails";
}

echo "\n\n";

$hash = false;
if($hash!==0){
    echo "false passes";
}else{
    echo "false fails";
}
```

Output:

```
true passes

false passes
```

You should change `$hash!==0` to `$hash` or `$hash!==false`.  `$hash!=0` will work, but it may confuse a future developer's understanding of your code.

Comment: i tried this `if ($hash === true) { echo "SUCCESS"; } else { echo "wrnng"; }` before an this `if ($hash !== 0 && $emailErr2 == "" && $passwordErr2 == "")` statemnt and it anyways echo's wrong EVEN if I type in right pass

Comment: You will need to add some checkpoints.  Volunteers will not be able to help you with the current amount of information.  Try to isolate which conditions are working as expected and which ones are not.  After isolating, tell us what values are involved and we should be able to help.

Comment: So if you are saying that using if($hash) {echo 'Success';} else {echo 'Failed';} always results in 'Failed' being printed I would suspect that your password and hash password are not matching. Are you 1000% sure that they are correct? You don't have something like truncation in your password field in the database happening or something like that?

Comment: thank you guys, so much, there was a problem with $hash , $hash != 0 works, but just $hash doesnt, anyway, my problem is solved, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if($hash && $emailErr2=="" &&  $passwordErr2==""){
```

The problem maybe with the `===` as it also compares the type.

Otherwise just try using `$hash!=0` instead of `$hash!==0`

Hope it works.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I just came back to this page and noticed this duplicate answer.  This new user has copied the technique that I posted a hour earlier.  I'm not sure this answer should be rewarded.

Comment: Hey, sorry but I hadn't seen your answer when I posted mine. I assure you that I had not copied the answer. As you can see I have even stated the reason it may not have been working. Please try and understand I had not copied the answer from you.

Comment: @Namah I understand, but exact duplicate answers should be avoided.  In the future, do read all of the pre-existing answers (there were only two) before posting.

Comment: Yeah, I will keep that in mind. I am really sorry that you felt that way. For what its worth, I gave you an up vote from my side. Although I doubt it counts (as I am new).

Comment: Also @AlivetoDie Thank you so much. It really counts.